# Change date to required format

Tags: excel

I have some dates in a column in Excel displayed as:

```
"14-Dec" "14-Jul" etc
```

and in the formula bar showing as `12/14/2015`, `7/14/2015`.

The date is supposed to be `2014-Dec` and `2014-Jul`.

Is there a way in which I can change it to `2014-12-01`?

Comment: If the cell contains **14 December 2014** why display it as **2014-12-01**??

Comment: The cell has incorrect date.. its supposed to have only year-month.. ie. the format is supposed to be yy-mmm and then i need to change the format to yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom format of:

```
yyyy-mm"-01"
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way i can get it to use the custom format using text function? eg =text($A1,"yyyy-mm-01") gives me an error.